# Пост/пре инкремент

Tags: php

```
$a = 10;
$a = $a + $a++; // $a = 21

$a = 10;
$a = $a + ++$a; // $a = 22
```

Почему так происходит? Какой алгоритм вычисления?

Comment: А вы что ожидаете?

Comment: Алгоритм именно такой. Пост-инкремент (а++) возвращает значение ДО добавления единички, ++а - после. В итоге первое значение на единичку меньше.

Comment: А что вернет `$a=10; $a=$a++ + ++$a;` в пхп? Ожидаемые 23, или больше? Или опять зависит от версии РНР?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в C++ эта ситуация — undefined behaviour. Так что вопрос не так уж тривиален. В хорошем ответе хотелось бы видеть четкое объяснение того, в каком порядке выполняются операторы (в том числе пост–инкремент) в PHP.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = 10;
$a = $a + $a++; // $a = 21
```

$a++ - выполнится после +

```
$a = 10;
$a = $a + ++$a; // $a = 22
```

++$a - выполнится перед +

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php