# А что будет, если выполнить $a++ + ++$a?

Tags: php, инкремент, неопределённое-поведение

Навеяно [вопросом про пре/постинкремент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437009). Код:

```
<?php
$a=10;
$a=$a++ + ++$a;
echo $a;
```

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/rZ9g8p) выдает 22, ожидалось 23.  Модификация с выставлением приоритетов `$a=($a++) + (++$a);` не спасает. Вопрос: Поведение пре/пост-инкремента описано в интерпретаторе PHP, или это классический undefined behavior?

Апдейт: Да, перепутал код для 23, там было именно `$a = ++$a + ++$a`, здесь 22 без вопросов, так как пред-инкремент один. А вот вариант `$a= ++$a * (++$a + 2);` оказался куда интереснее - ответ на Ideone 154! Второй вариант, если вначале вычисляется `(++$a +2)`, 12*13 = 156. Вопрос в силе - поведение интерпретатора PHP при вычислении выражений с пред/постинкрементом задано, или отличается в зависимости от реализации?

Comment: Да уж. Могу только предположить, что из-за левой ассоциативности (выполнение слева направо) оператора умножения, выражение вычислялось так: `$a = (++$a) * (++$a + 2)`. Документально пока подтвердить не могу.

Comment: @AlexBelyaev Похоже, правильный ответ все-таки "вначале вычисляются все пред/постинкременты, а потом выражение", иначе второй `++$a` вычислялся бы первым, и ответ был бы 156.

Comment: дык это очевидно -- мы уже по факту выяснили, что сначала посчитались инкременты. Я в своём комменте рассуждал почему они вдруг таким образом решили посчитаться. Ибо я например не нашёл в доках ничего о сравнительном приоритете скобок и инкрементов. Может плохо смотрел :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю почему вы ожидали 23 :) Есть официальный [мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php), где чёрным по белому написано, что префиксный инкремент **увеличивает** $a на единицу, **затем возвращает** значение $a. А постфиксный инкремент **возвращает значение** $a, **затем** увеличивает $a на единицу. Описан также [приоритет операторов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php): инкременты до арифметических действий (сложение и вычитание, естественно после умножения и деления).

Итак:

```
$a = $a++ + ++$a;
// $a++ сначала возвращает 10, потом увеличивается ($a == 11)
// ++$a сначала увеличивается ($a == 12), затем уже возвращается в выражение 
// 10 + 12 = 22
```

Вероятно, скажу очевидные вещи, но в реальной жизни такой неочевидный код писать не нужно. Относитесь, пожалуйста, к этому как к разминке для ума. Хотя, на мой взгляд, интегралы порешать полезнее будет :)

Comment: Немного обновил вопрос. Да, был неправ :)

Comment: Добавил в ответ ссылку на приоритет операторов. Думаю, undefined behavior подозревали именно в этом моменте.

Answer (score 1):

типичный код-майндфак в деле

у меня вышло

```
10+11

21+1
```

почему ожидалось 23 не понял

проверночные примеры 
с прединкрементом

```
$i = 5;
$i = ++$i + ++$i;
echo $i;//13
```

и пост

```
$i = 5;
$i = $i++ + $i++;
echo $i;//11
```