# += с пре и пост-инкрементами

Tags: php, инкремент, неопределённое-поведение

Ну ладно, [разобрали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437009/181472) разные [ситуации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437027/181472) с инкрементами. А если добавить `+=`?

```
$a = 10;
$a += $a++;
```

> [21](https://ideone.com/jXHbt4)

```
$a = 10;
$a += ++$a;
```

> [22](https://ideone.com/BGSlqH)

```
$a = 10;
$a += $a++ + ++$a;
```

> [34](https://ideone.com/5wjLVG)

Также пока непонятным остается такое:

```
$a = 10;
$a = $a++ + $a++;
```

> [21](https://ideone.com/whZpRO)

Особенно интересно: **когда происходит пост-инкрементация**: сразу после того, как берется значение или только когда вычисляется все выражение?

Зависит ли это от реализации интерпретатора? От какой-нибудь JIT-оптимизации?

Comment: То будет то же, что и ожидалось. Знаки доллара только надо расставить. После того, как берется значение.

Comment: @Etki: Похоже, что инкрементация происходит строго сразу. Почитал руководство по ссылке, из него это не очевидно.

Comment: Рассмотрите еще `$a += $a++ + $a++ + $a++`. Сам не пробовал, но на Хабре писали, что при тройном сложении происходит нечто неинтуитивное, хотя и понятное для того, кто знает принцип работы интерпретатора.

Comment: Может, [Приоритет операторов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php) внесёт ясность в ваши вопросы?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: вроде как это от уже имеющихся не слишком отличается, разве нет?

Comment: @Sergiks: вопрос не совсем об этом. Я точно помню, что в C в данной ситуации имеется неопределенное поведение. Вопрос: так ли это в PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27772768/2790048

Comment: @PavelMayorov 46 выходит, может в Сях и проблема есть, в РНР её точно нет. Считаем: первый $a++ выдает 10, второй 11, третий 12, а в $a уже 13, итого 13+33 = 46.

Comment: Значит, этой проблемы нет конкретно в этом случае. В сях как раз никакой проблемы нет - там так просто не следует делать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потестировал немного - у меня получилось, что вычисление пред/постинкремента идет строго слева направо перед вычислением выражения, а уже потом выражение считается по общим правилам. То есть вначале выполняются все инкременты с возвращением значения, потом из возвращенных значений собирается результат выражения. Тестирован на [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_terminal_online.php), [Online PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) и [Ideone](https://ideone.com). Везде поведение интерпретатора PHP было одинаковым.

Comment: Я бы тестировал на `php -a` :)

Comment: @AlexBelyaev А нет у меня рядом пых-дистриба. Но tutorialspoint мне предложил выполнить именно `php` из командной строки, на где-то-в-облаке развернутом терминале. С шеллом из-под рута, ага :D